# Input file to multiple matrices

Tags: python, list, file, matrix, readline

I know there are related threads, but I've searched and none of them helped me with my problem.

I have a input text file with square matrices that looks as follows:

1 2 3
4 5 6 
7 8 9
*
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
25 26 27 28 29
30 31 32 33 34

Now there could be more matrices following, all with a `*` in between them.

I want to separate the matrices **(without using numpy!)** and then using list within lists to work with them (list comprehension might be useful I guess), all the entries would be integers. The first matrix would then look as follows `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and the second one would be `[[10,11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18,19],[20,21,22,23,24],[25,26,27,28,29],[31,31,32,33,34]]` and so on.

My plan was to separate the matrices in their own list entries and then (using the fact that the matrices are square, and therefore it can easily be determined how many integers one list entry should contain) using some list comprehension to change the strings into integers. But I'm stuck at the very beginning.

```
matrix = open('input.txt','r').read()
matrix = matrix.replace('\n',' ')
list = matrix.split('* ')
```

Now if I `print list` I get `['1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9', '10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34']`

The problem is that I'm now stuck with two strings instead of a list of integers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Instead of reading the file at once; try reading it line by line, splitting each line using `" "` as a separator, append those to a list of list of lists (a list of list to hold an individual matrix, and the third one to hold multiple matrices), and initialise a new list whenever the line is simply an `*` character. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: I'm trying to work that out now, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mat_list = [[[int(num_str) for num_str in line.split()] for line in inner_mat.split('\n')] for inner_mat in open('input_mat.txt','r').read().split('\n*\n')]
```

[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[10, 11, 12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [20, 21, 22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27, 28, 29], [30, 31, 32, 33, 34]]]

Comment: This is the output I'm looking for but your code doesn't provide that for me. Could you explain the code used?

Comment: read the input as one string, split on \n*\n, you get your inner matrices, then split each inner matrix on newLine \n, you have a row of each inner matrix, then split each row on space and convert it to integer

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have strings, split each string on space and convert each little string to an integer. After that, you can convert each list of strings to a square "matrix" (list of lists).

An additional point: do not use `list` as a variable name. That conflicts with the built-in `list` type. In this code I used the name `mylist`.

```
newlist = [[int(nstr) for nstr in v.split()] for v in mylist]
# Now convert each list of strings to a square "matrix" (list of lists)
```

However, note that the approach given by @Selcuk in his comment is a better way to solve your overall problem. Though it would be a little easier to read the entire file into memory and split on the stars, then split each line into its integers. This would result in easier code but larger memory usage.

Comment: I won't be using it for very large files, so that shouldn't be too much of a consideration. Easier code is a preference for me, since I'm pretty new to python. The \n at the end of the lines gives me some trouble.

Comment: @Mathbeginner `.split()` will take care of the extra `\n` for you.